# Symfony entity class seems not to be a managed Doctrine entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I try to create a form with a dropdown menu which holds all entries of a database table named "main_category".

Here is my TemplateUploadType form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->setAction('upload')
        ->setMethod('POST')

        ->add('service_category', 'entity', array(
                'label' => 'tpl_upload_service_category_label',
                'class' => '\AppBundle\Entity\MainCategory',
                'placeholder' => 'tpl_upload_service_category_placeholder',
                'attr' => array(
                    'required' => 'true',
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ),
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('m')
                        ->orderBy('m.serviceCategoryId', 'ASC');
                },
            )
        )

        // button
        ->add('submit', 'submit', array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'btn btn-default'
                )
            )
        );
}
```

And here is my "MainCategory" entity which I created using the doctrine command line tool:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * MainCategory
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="main_category")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class MainCategory
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="service_category_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $serviceCategoryId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="service_category", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $serviceCategory = '';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="main_category", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $mainCategory = 'SAP';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="comment", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $comment;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Costfactor", inversedBy="scid")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="category_has_costfactor",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="scid", referencedColumnName="service_category_id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cfid", referencedColumnName="costfactor_id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $cfid;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CcRef", inversedBy="serviceCategory")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="cc_master",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="service_category_id", referencedColumnName="service_category_id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cc_parameter_id", referencedColumnName="cc_parameter_id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $ccParameter;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="KpiRef", inversedBy="serviceCategory")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="kpi_master",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="service_category_id", referencedColumnName="service_category_id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="kpi_parameter_id", referencedColumnName="kpi_parameter_id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $kpiParameter;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="SecRef", inversedBy="serviceCategory")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="sec_master",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="service_category_id", referencedColumnName="service_category_id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sec_parameter_id", referencedColumnName="sec_parameter_id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $secParameter;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="SlRef", inversedBy="serviceCategory")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="sl_master",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="service_category_id", referencedColumnName="service_category_id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sl_parameter_id", referencedColumnName="sl_parameter_id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $slParameter;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cfid = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->ccParameter = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->kpiParameter = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->secParameter = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->slParameter = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get serviceCategoryId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getServiceCategoryId()
    {
        return $this->serviceCategoryId;
    }

    /**
     * Set serviceCategory
     *
     * @param string $serviceCategory
     * @return MainCategory
     */
    public function setServiceCategory($serviceCategory)
    {
        $this->serviceCategory = $serviceCategory;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get serviceCategory
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getServiceCategory()
    {
        return $this->serviceCategory;
    }

    /**
     * Set mainCategory
     *
     * @param string $mainCategory
     * @return MainCategory
     */
    public function setMainCategory($mainCategory)
    {
        $this->mainCategory = $mainCategory;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get mainCategory
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getMainCategory()
    {
        return $this->mainCategory;
    }

    /**
     * Set comment
     *
     * @param string $comment
     * @return MainCategory
     */
    public function setComment($comment)
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get comment
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getComment()
    {
        return $this->comment;
    }

    /**
     * Add cfid
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Costfactor $cfid
     * @return MainCategory
     */
    public function addCfid(\AppBundle\Entity\Costfactor $cfid)
    {
        $this->cfid[] = $cfid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove cfid
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Costfactor $cfid
     */
    public function removeCfid(\AppBundle\Entity\Costfactor $cfid)
    {
        $this->cfid->removeElement($cfid);
    }

    /**
     * Get cfid
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getCfid()
    {
        return $this->cfid;
    }

    /**
     * Add ccParameter
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\CcRef $ccParameter
     * @return MainCategory
     */
    public function addCcParameter(\AppBundle\Entity\CcRef $ccParameter)
    {
        $this->ccParameter[] = $ccParameter;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove ccParameter
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\CcRef $ccParameter
     */
    public function removeCcParameter(\AppBundle\Entity\CcRef $ccParameter)
    {
        $this->ccParameter->removeElement($ccParameter);
    }

    /**
     * Get ccParameter
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getCcParameter()
    {
        return $this->ccParameter;
    }

    /**
     * Add kpiParameter
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\KpiRef $kpiParameter
     * @return MainCategory
     */
    public function addKpiParameter(\AppBundle\Entity\KpiRef $kpiParameter)
    {
        $this->kpiParameter[] = $kpiParameter;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove kpiParameter
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\KpiRef $kpiParameter
     */
    public function removeKpiParameter(\AppBundle\Entity\KpiRef $kpiParameter)
    {
        $this->kpiParameter->removeElement($kpiParameter);
    }

    /**
     * Get kpiParameter
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getKpiParameter()
    {
        return $this->kpiParameter;
    }

    /**
     * Add secParameter
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\SecRef $secParameter
     * @return MainCategory
     */
    public function addSecParameter(\AppBundle\Entity\SecRef $secParameter)
    {
        $this->secParameter[] = $secParameter;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove secParameter
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\SecRef $secParameter
     */
    public function removeSecParameter(\AppBundle\Entity\SecRef $secParameter)
    {
        $this->secParameter->removeElement($secParameter);
    }

    /**
     * Get secParameter
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getSecParameter()
    {
        return $this->secParameter;
    }

    /**
     * Add slParameter
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\SlRef $slParameter
     * @return MainCategory
     */
    public function addSlParameter(\AppBundle\Entity\SlRef $slParameter)
    {
        $this->slParameter[] = $slParameter;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove slParameter
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\SlRef $slParameter
     */
    public function removeSlParameter(\AppBundle\Entity\SlRef $slParameter)
    {
        $this->slParameter->removeElement($slParameter);
    }

    /**
     * Get slParameter
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getSlParameter()
    {
        return $this->slParameter;
    }
}
```

As a result of using above code I recieve the error message:
Class "\AppBundle\Entity\MainCategory" seems not to be a managed Doctrine entity. Did you forget to map it?

What am I doing wrong? If you need more information please let me know.

Comment: did you create schema?

Comment: @malcolm: What exactly do you mean? I created the entity class using the command "php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert ... " based on an existing database table. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Ok, and you cleared the cache?

Comment: Yes, I did."php app/console cache:clear"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to @malcolm

First I changed my TemplateUploadType form so there was no slash at the beginning of the line:

```
'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\MainCategory',
```

This led to another error called *"Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class AppBundle\Entity\MainCategory could not be converted to string"*. Investigating this I found the answer [in this blog post](http://blog.jonathanargentiero.com/symfony2-doctrine-catchable-fatal-error-object-of-class-xyz-could-not-be-converted-to-string-in-doctrinedbalstatement-php-line-131/).

Basically I had to overwrite the __toString() function inside my entity class.

```
public function __toString()
{
    return strval($this->serviceCategory);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
'class' => '\AppBundle\Entity\MainCategory',
```

Remove first trailing slash:

```
'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\MainCategory',
```

Comment: No, that is not the problem. I have seen several different styles of this class mapping command. This change causes another error called "Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class AppBundle\Entity\MainCategory could not be converted to string". Anyway how I tried to change this part.

Comment: Ok, so I have no idea :)

Comment: Thank you anyway. I think I found an odd explanation for this because of your support. I will write an answer here soon.